# Multi-Insert Shorthand with Primary Key & Identity

Tags: sql, insert, auto-increment, shorthand

I would like a shorthand (if possible) for inserting multiple records into a table which has a primary key and IsIdentity property. For example, say I have a table called 'People' with the following columns:
- ID (Primary Key, and Identity [i.e. autoincrementing])
- Name (not null)
- Email (not null)

An insert statement excluding the auto-incrementing ID column is perfectly valid, such as:

```
INSERT INTO People VALUES ('George', 'george@email.com')
```

But if I want to insert multiple values in the same statement, **ideally** that could be done something like this where I **don't have to explicitly specify the column names**:

```
INSERT INTO People VALUES (
   (auto, 'George', 'george@email.com'),
   (auto, 'Mary', 'mary@email.com')
)
```

The best solution I could find was something like this:

```
INSERT INTO People (
   SELECT 'George', 'george@email.com',
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Mary', 'mary@email.com'
)
```

I suppose you could argue, this is a somewhat meaningless pursuit, but I wanted the query itself to be extensible along with the table design. For example, if a column name changed, or more columns were added I wouldn't have to change this everywhere in the code.

Cheers :)

Comment: Most of the time the easiest way is not the best way...bear that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert multiple rows like this:

```
INSERT INTO `People` (`name`,`email`) VALUES ('George', 'George@test.com'),('Mary', 'LittleLamb@test.com');
```

EDIT:

```
mysql> create table `test`(
    -> `id` int(10) unsigned not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> `name` varchar(255) not null default 'N/A/',
    -> `email` varchar(255) not null default 'N/A/',
    -> PRIMARY KEY(`id`) 
    -> )ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (null, 'Name 1', 'Email 1'),(null, 'Name 2','Email 2');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from `test`;
+----+--------+---------+
| id | name   | email   |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 | Name 1 | Email 1 |
|  2 | Name 2 | Email 2 |
+----+--------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As long as your primary key is set to auto increment, you can nullify the field and it will auto set the value to the auto increment value.

Comment: Sorry, but perhaps you missed my bolded comment on NOT explicitly including the property names, lol. I appreciate the attempt though :)

Comment: You don't technically "have" to, I do it out of habit. As long as you store a value for each field you are alright.

Comment: If people has user_id, name, and email in that order you should do VALUES (null, 'Name', 'Email'),(null, 'Name 2', 'Email 2') etc

Comment: So apparently it can be done in MySQL, but not in MSSQL when the Identity (MySQL "Auto_Increment" equivalent) property is invoked. Anyway, I've been reading that auto incrementing isn't necessarily a good idea for your Primary Key field. ~Thanks for sticking with me :)

Comment: Not a problem at all, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what database you are using. Some databases allow multiple value sets:

```
insert into People values
(auto, 'George', 'george@email.com'),
(auto, 'Mary', 'mary@email.com')
```

Comment: Specifically MS SQL 2008 R2, though I wonder if Denali will implement this functionality?

Comment: @Chiramisu: actually, this feature was introduced in SQL Server 2008 - and I'm pretty sure it'll still be there in Denali (or why do you think it'll be removed???)

Comment: Well if it does exist in 2008, I have yet to see how to use it. >.<